# Why does compiler return `dynamic` when it should return a specific type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, .net-framework-version

Below is the exact code I am running. Why does the compiler return `dynamic` and not type `MyClass`?

My project is running on .NET Framework 4.7.2, but I configured it to use latest C# by adding `public static class IsExternalInit { }` and

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My code:

```
internal class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }

    static class MyParser
    {
        public static MyClass Parse(dynamic data)
        {
            return new MyClass();
        }
    }

    static void Do(dynamic data)
    {
        var parsedObj = MyParser.Parse(data);
        ...
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Do(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(""));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you link to the docs where it says “when one of parameters of an expression is dynamic whole expression returns static type (sometimes or always)”?

Comment: @ericlippert's answer is absolutely correct. But a hint for your next question, please explain what line of code you are referring to. Something like: "In the debugger, if I  inspect the type of `parsedObj`  it's `dynamic`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does compiler return `dynamic` when it should return a specific type?

The question presupposes a falsehood. The compiler's behaviour is correct, so asking why it *should* do an incorrect thing makes it hard to answer your question.

Instead I'll answer the question "what section of the specification determines when the compiler should classify an invocation as dynamic?"

---

I refer you to section 11.7.8.1 of the specification, which states:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11781-general

> An invocation_expression is dynamically bound (§11.3.3) if at least
> one of the following holds:
>
> - The primary_expression has compile-time type dynamic.
> - At least one argument of the optional argument_list has compile-time type dynamic.
>
> In this case, the compiler classifies the invocation_expression as a
> value of type dynamic.

`data` is "at least one argument" that has type `dynamic`, so there you go.

In your specific case, the section on additional error checks applies -- but this section does not affect the classification of the invocation's type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1165-compile-time-checking-of-dynamic-member-invocation

---

If your "why" question was not answered by a reference to the specification, then I'd encourage you to reformulate it as a "what" question.  [It's hard to know when a "why" question has been answered satisfactorily.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio/323382#323382)

Comment: `optional argument list` so shouldn’t it only take effect if argument would have been declared as `dynamic data = null` ?

Comment: @RandRandom: I think maybe you're confused about what "optional argument list" refers to. It refers to this *argument list*: `MyParser.Parse(data)`, not the *formal parameter list* `Do(dynamic data)`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I mean `public static MyClass Parse(dynamic data)` vs `public static MyClass Parse(dynamic data = null)` the later is an optional argument so I thought the reference is referring to this? but since the method doesn’t contain an optional argument it shouldn’t apply or?

Comment: @RandRandom: The specification would be correct even without the word "optional" in there. "At least one argument of the argument_list has compile-time type dynamic." would suffice. So don't get hung up on the word "optional". It's just reminding the reader that the grammar allows the argument list to be empty. (Plainly if it is empty then the "at least one" requirement is not met.)

Comment: @RandRandom: I think maybe you're mis-parsing the sentence. It is "the optional (argument list)", not "the (optional argument) list".  That is, the argument list is optional. It's not referring to "the list of optional arguments".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though I am still interested as to what the reasoning behind that decision was. Have to agree with OP that it seems „wrong“ for a method with a return type to change its return type to dynamic just because of the argument. What could possibly be the influence of the argument that the compiler needs to alter the return type to dynamic.

Comment: I don't think it is changing the return type. The object instance that is returned is of type `MyClass`, and you can call it using `MyClass parsedObj = MyParser.Parse(data);`. When you declare a variable using `var` instead of a specific type, the compiler has to infer the type you want to declare the variable as, and since you're working with dynamics, it assumes you want to continue to do so. You don't have to use `var` of course.

Comment: @RandRandom: The design principle is: "dynamic" turns off the compile-time type checker, and **when you turn it off, it is turned off**.  If you don't want to turn off the compile-time type checker, don't use dynamic!

Comment: '"dynamic" turns off the compile-time type checker' and replaces it with runtime binding. If you had multiple `Parse()` methods with different arguments, each execution of the method may call a different function, with a different return type. Hence why the type of the returned variable is `dynamic`. The compiler makes no attempt to guess what runtime binding will do.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That's correct. The usual response to this point is that in this *specific* case the compiler could know that dynamic binding will *always* choose the same method. But "the compiler makes every possible logical inference even when the developer wants the logical inference system turned off" is not a design principle of C#. "Keep the rules simple and understandable whenever possible" is!